# Toggle text stored in data attribute on a click event

Tags: jquery

So I am trying to get the text in the button to toggle between strings stored in the data attributes:

```
<button class="toggleButton6 book1" data-starttext="Starting Text" data secondtext="Toggled Text">Starting Text</button>
```

So far I can get the text to change only for the first click event. I need to add something to get the text to toggle back and forth with unlimited click events:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.book1').on('click', function(){
    var textVariable = $(this).data("secondtext");
    $(this).text(textVariable);
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/nigelNSF/pen/Dfpak

Comment: Possible typo in your code: `data secondtext`. Should be `data-secondtext`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need 2 data as you have the `firsttext` as `button.text()`, so change your html like below to have just 1 data.. lets say `toggletext`

```
<button class="toggleButton6 book1" data-toggletext="Toggled Text" >Starting Text</button>
```

And then toggle the value of `toggletext` and `button.text()` in the script like below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.book1').on('click', function(){
        var textVariable = $(this).data("toggletext");          
        $(this).data('toggletext', $(this).text()).text(textVariable);

  });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://codepen.io/seraphzz/full/IJLBi

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.book1').on('click', function(){
      var textVariable = $(this).data("secondtext");
      var temp = $(this).text();
      $(this).text(textVariable).data("secondtext", temp);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.book1').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).text() == $(this).attr('data-starttext'))
        $(this).text($(this).attr('data-secondtext'));
    else 
        $(this).text($(this).attr('data-starttext'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As everybody else says: you must check the state of the text by comparing it to `starttext` or `secondtext` and explicitly setting the value of your text field accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.book1').on('click', function(){
    var second = $(this).data("secondtext");
    var start = $(this).data("starttext");
    if (second === $(this).text()) {
      $(this).text(start);
    } else {
      $(this).text(second);
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://cdpn.io/objim).